# JS handling drop down boxes

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

i have this script which allows the users to select from Dropdown 1, and it will fill Dropdown 2 with values. THOUGH the problem here is that once it fills, the original "item" called "-- Välj län först --" disappears, which i do not want it to do. I just want the new values to fill up under it.
Could someone take a look at the code i supply below and see if there is an easy fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

http://pastebin.com/aqvX222V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this : **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dVP62/4/)**

```
function showSubKommun(subCat,selectObj){
   selectObj.length=kommun[subCat].length+1;
   for(var n=1;n<=kommun[subCat].length;n++){
     selectObj[n].text=kommun[subCat][n-1];
     selectObj[n].value=kommun[subCat][n-1];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, though this partialy worked, since im getting an "Undefined" value at the bottom of Dropdown 2.

Comment: Welcome.. I missied out a small updation.. and the updated answer works perfectly... Happy to be Helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function showSubKommun(subCat,selectObj){
    selectObj.length=kommun[subCat].length+1;
    selectObj[0].text=kommun[0][0];
    selectObj[0].value=kommun[0][0];
    for(var n=0;n<kommun[subCat].length;n++){
        selectObj[n+1].text=kommun[subCat][n];
        selectObj[n+1].value=kommun[subCat][n];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work for me, but the solution above worked.

Comment: Opps, I've make some careless mistake, and seems the above solution is shorter.